# Array of structure: Structure members are Enum Variables

Tags: c, struct, enums

I'm trying to understand a code which is part of a reusable firmware development guide. The book is too difficult for me, but still, I'm trying to understand the code.

In a sample code came with the book, there's a syntax similar to below

```
typedef enum 
{

   DIO_MAX_MODE 
}DioMode_t;


typedef enum 
{
   DIO_PULLUP_DISABLED,     /*< Used to disable the internal pull-ups */
   DIO_PULLUP_ENABLED,      /*< Used to enable the internal pull-ups */
   DIO_MAX_RESISTOR         /*< Resistor states should be below this value */
}DioResistor_t;

typedef enum
{
    DIO_OUTPUT,
    DIO_INPUT
}DioDirection_t;



typedef struct 
{
    DioResistor_t Resistor;              /**< Pullup/Pulldown Resistor - ENABLED or DISABLED    */
    DioDirection_t Direction;      /**< Data Direction      - OUTPUT or INPUT           */
    DioMode_t Function;            /**< Mux Function        - Dio_Peri_Select           */
}DioConfig_t;
```

If I understand correctly, members of the struct are enum variables.

And in one part of the code developer assigns a value to it below way (Not exact, I'm trying to understand how this whole thing work by making a similar syntax of it)

```
 DioConfig_t config[] = {    {1, 2, 3}, 
                                {4, 5, 6}
 };
```

What's happening here? Is this possible??

When Initializing as above, does it affect the values of enums, which values are changing and how to access them?

**Edit:**

If I create a struct like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    struct test var[] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} }; 

    /* 
    struct test var[0] = {1, 2}
    struct test var[1] = {3, 4}
    */

    printf("%d %d\n", var[0].a, var[1].a);

    return 0;
```

I know what values are assigned to `a` and `b` based on which variable of struct I use to call them 
eg: var[0].a = 1 and var[1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rLd3XIiJBNB2C8M3WPOuE2SP_6rJvWC9).a = 3

But The code I've shown first has `enum` variables as struct members
So values assigned to struct members are

```
config[0].Resistor = 1
config[0].Direction = 2
config[0].Function = 3
```

Since these are `enum` variables, Will it change `enum` values, how ???

PS: It's only been few months since I started learning C. I use it for developing small embedded projects, I read several online tutorials and videos, learned about struct and pointers, but when I opened this
[code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rLd3XIiJBNB2C8M3WPOuE2SP_6rJvWC9), it didn't make much sense to me. Is that normal??

Comment: What exactly is puzzling you? The example is not good style, but I'm not sure if that is due to your "(Not exact,...)" copy of the real code. Is it that you can use numbers for enums?

Comment: Is the confusing part that the values `{4,5,6}` are not within valid values for the enums or is it something else?

Comment: The entire code can be found on the drive link I provided. Dio_cfg.c and Dio_cfg.h. The confusing part is when I initialize as above, how values are assigned to struct and enum

Comment: OK, then the values out of range for enums are not the issue. But it's still not clear which part is confusing you.

Comment: @Gerhardh I've edited the question. What you meant by out of range??

Comment: `DioResistor_t` defines values `0,1,2` but your snippet assigned value 4 to the field in second element of your array.

Comment: When initializing as this  `DioConfig_t config[] = {    {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };` Isn't this way values assigned `config[0].Resistor = 1` 
`config[0].Direction = 2`
`config[0].Function = 3`

Comment: Yes, it is. And then it continues: `config[1].Resistor = 4; config[1].Direction = 5; config[1].Function = 6;`

Answer (score 0):

> What's happening here? Is this possible??

The inner braces (`{1, 2, 3}` and `{4, 5, 6}`) initialize a `DioConfig_t` each. The outer braces initialize the array `config[]` with the two `DioConfig_t` defined by the inner braces. It is equivalent to this:

```
DioConfig_t a = {1, 2, 3};
DioConfig_t b = {4, 5, 6};
DioConfig_t config[] = {a, b};
```

What's confusing is that the braces do two different thing here. One is initializing a struct, and the other is initializing an array.

Note: I am not sure that my terminology is 100% correct, and when I say "they are equivalent", I am not considering that the performance might be different depending on the level of compiler optimization.

> It didn't make much sense to me. Is that normal?

Are you asking whether it is normal to be confused by some C code? Absolutely. There's a lot of tricks, pitfalls and obscure stuff in the language, even people who worked with it for years learn something new and get confused/baffled by some tricky C code here and then. Don't let this discourage you.

Comment: But if create a normal `strcut test` with variables `int a` `int b` and create struct variable as `struct test var[] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4}}` Then as per your explanation `printf("%d %d\n", var[0].a, var[1].a);`  should give 1 and 2 but the assigned values are **1, 3** Also how `enum` values are affected?

Comment: That's how it is supposed to be. In your example, var[0] is {1, 2} and var[1] is {3, 4}, and you are printing their first value each.

Comment: Since `struct` members are enum, how this changes `enum` values??

Comment: It doesn't modify the underlying enum values. Those enums in `struct DioConfig_t`, they're basically integers with a bit more type safety. As seen in the code that you provided, you can assign `6` to `DioMode_t Function`, as if `Function` was an `int` instead. In the end, it's just a space of (probably) 4 bytes anyway. I'd say it's bad design to assign `6` to `DioMode_t Function`, but it's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

Basically enum is an another method to define integer constants, so an enum variable must take the same memory as that of an integer variable so basically it can hold any integer value.In your case an enum  variable of type `DioResistor_t` can hold values other than 0(`DIO_PULLUP_DISABLED`), 1(`DIO_PULLUP_ENABLED`) and 2(`DIO_MAX_RESISTOR`). So initializing other values to the enum structure element is okay(but it can result in invalid output).

We will now discuss the reason for define structure elements as enum. For that consider the 2 scenarios given below.

Case 1: The `DioConfig_t` structure is defined as given below:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int Resistor;
    unsigned int Direction;
    unsigned int Function;
}DioConfig_t;
```

Case 2: The `DioConfig_t` structure is defined as given in your code.

Now if a developer wants to configure a pin as an output pin with pull resistor and in maximum mode.

In the first case he needs to find the values for Resistor, Direction and Function variables of configuration structure `DioConfig_t` that will configure the pin as he required but in the second case he can easily configure it as all the required values of the variables are defined in enum.

The configuration in the above 2 cases are given below:

Case 1:

```
    Dio_Config_t dio_configuration;
    dio_configuration.Resistor = 1;
    dio_configuration.Direction = 0;
    dio_configuration.Function = 0;
```

Case 2:

```
    Dio_Config_t dio_configuration;
    dio_configuration.Resistor = DIO_PULLUP_ENABLED;
    dio_configuration.Direction = DIO_OUTPUT;
    dio_configuration.Function = DIO_MAX_MODE;
```

As you can see the code in the second case is easier to understand and it is safer as the values will not be accidently changed easily.

Answer (score 0):

An `enum` is a special case of an integer type.  It is legal in C to assign values to an `enum` variable that fall outside of that range.

Assigning an out-of-range value to an `enum` variable also has no effect on any `enum` constants that were defined.  Note also that the fact that the variable in question is a member of a struct doesn't change anything.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum f {
    F1,
    F2,
    F3
} f;

int main()
{
    f x = 4;
    printf("F1=%d\n", F1);
    printf("F2=%d\n", F2);
    printf("F3=%d\n", F3);
    printf("x=%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
F1=0
F2=1
F3=2
x=4
```

In this example, the value 4 is assigned to the variable of type `f`, even though the values of the associated `enum` are 0, 1, and 2.